# installing older version of snapd to 2.37

Tags: software-installation

how can I install the old version of snapd 2.37 to make a vulnerable machine for my assignment? I am running 22.04 ubuntu.

Comment: You don't. You install the release that runs with the version you want.

Comment: snaps also update to the newest version so even if you could install an old version it would 1st upgrade itself.

Comment: @Rinzwind ic, look like I need to find a new vulnerability.  Thanks

Comment: You need to install Ubuntu 18.04 *without* the bionic-upgrades nor bionic-security pockets. Then you must manually download the version of snapd from Launchpad and install it into the 18.04 machine. Not the easiest. You're fighting years of safe-and-secure-by-default design.

Comment: Thanks. For your input. I can only work on the 22.04. Look like I really need to look for a new 1.